What is the source of עתיד בהוראת עבר?
BH
In the רמב"ם לעם commentary of Yad HaChazaka on the sentence כל התורה כתבה משה רבנו קדם שימות it says that the word ימות is classified as the concept of עתיד בהוראת עבר (A word that is in the future tense that is to be translated/explained in the past tense.) and it brings an example that this is like “טֶ֣רֶם יִצְמָ֑ח” “before [they] sprouted” from Gen 2:5
‎וְכֹ֣ל ׀ שִׂ֣יחַ הַשָּׂדֶ֗ה טֶ֚רֶם יִֽהְיֶ֣ה בָאָ֔רֶץ וְכׇל־עֵ֥שֶׂב הַשָּׂדֶ֖ה טֶ֣רֶם יִצְמָ֑ח when no shrub of the field was yet on earth and no grasses of the field had yet sprouted” also which has a yud which usually teaches future tense although here is translated in past form. What is the source of this concept of עתיד בהוראת עבר?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_in_the_past

Biblical Hebrew verbs primarily signified aspects, and not tenses. The yiqtol conjugation signifies the imperfective aspect, defined by Wikipedia as signifying "ongoing, habitual, repeated, or similar semantic roles, whether that situation occurs in the past, present, or future."
